# Token for prevention of CSRF doesn't work on live server

Tags: php

I wrote a script which generates an authentication token in order to prevent CSRF attacks.
It works well on local server but returns the `403` error on live server

Here is the code that checks if a token already exists or not

```
    // Generate authentication token to prevent CRSF attacks
// Check if a token is present for the current session
if (!isset($_SESSION["auth_token"])) {
    // No token present, generate a new one
    $auth_token = bin2hex(random_bytes(35));
    $_SESSION["auth_token"] = $auth_token;
} else {
    // Reuse the token
    $auth_token = $_SESSION["auth_token"];
}
```

And here is the code that validates the token upon submission

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Validate token to avoid CSRF attacks
$token = trim($_POST['auth_token']);
if (!isset($token) || !isset($_SESSION['auth_token']) || $token !== $auth_token) {
    // show an error message
    echo '<h1 class="error">Error: invalid form submission</h1><p>Your request was denied as this request could not be verified.</p>';
    // return 403 http status code
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
    exit();
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I checked in on my error_log.php and this was the error displayed

`session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/refermec/public_html/user/login.php on line 15`

I have the same code as stated earlier in all pages with a form that requires authentication

Comment: And is the route to _set_ that token for the user accidentally locked behind code that requires "already having a token"? ;)

Comment: Can you validate if the 403 is being generated by PHP `http_response_code(403);`, or by your web server?

Comment: Also I don't see where `$token` is ever set -- `if (!isset($token) ` according to this example will always pass -- Unless it's set somewhere we can't see ..

Comment: @Zak how can I do that ? though the error message being displayed is same as the error message I echoed

Comment: @Zak it is set in the code . I edited it already

Comment: **UPDATE** That error tells all.  You are outputting a header, or HTML, or some kind of echo/output **before** `session_start();`

Comment: Oh oh.. it's only an html comment and php comment I have right before `session_start`

Comment: Did that solve it?

Comment: Yes it did...I guess the php tags comes first no matter what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error, you have content ABOVE `session_start();`  Once any content, no matter a HTML comment, an `echo`, a `header()` happens before `session_start();`, php will throw that error.

All these things need to come AFTER the `session_start();`   ...

Make sure `session_start();` is at the top of the file, or at the top of an included file.

Answer (score -4):

you need to add session table like this

```
php artisan session:table

composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate
```

change .env to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

also modify config/session.php

```
'domain' => '.yourdomain.com'
```

after that clear your browser's cache and cookies.

Comment: Nowhere does OP state they are using Laravel or Artisan ..

Comment: This answer doesn't seem relevant to the question asked.